# Partition-Like Counting

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Fix $k,n\geq 1$.  I wish to know the number of ways of dividing $n$ up as follows.  First find $c_1,c_2,\ldots ,c_k$ such that $c_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_ic_i=n$.  Then take each $c_i$ and find $c_{i,1},\ldots ,c_{i,n}$ such that $c_{i,m}\geq 0$ and $\sum_mmc_{i,m}=c_i$.  How many ways are there to do this?

Comment: The "partitions" tag is a bit misleading, since, if I get you right, you don't want $c_1\geq c_2\geq ...$?

Comment: Anyway, generating functions should do the job. Denoting your number by $p_{n,k}$, we have $\left(\sum\limits_{\ell\in\mathbb N}\text{number of partitions of }\ell\cdot T^{\ell}\right)^k=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}p_{n,k}T^n$.

Comment: ... and this means $\left(\prod\limits_{u=1}^{\infty}\left(1-T^u\right)\right)^{-k}=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}p_{n,k}T^n$.

Comment: Here is $k=2$: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000712

Comment: $k=3$: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000716. $k=4$: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A023003. I hope you can find the rest on your own.

Comment: The "representation theory" tag doesn't seem to be appropriate

Comment: The representation theory tag is there since this counting comes up in the case of $\lambda$-rings and I thought someone else may have encountered it.